# Not printing all the values of a function in C

Tags: c, arrays, function, char, return

```
#include <stdio.h>
void pp(int);
int main()
{
    int a[5]={4,5,7,1,9};
    int i;
    for(i=0;i<5;++i)
    pp(a[i]);


    return 0;
}
void pp(int n)
{
    char a[6]={'0','0','0','0','0','\0'};
    int x,i;
    int l=4;
    while(n)
    {
        x=n%2;
        a[l--]=x+'0';
        n=n/2;
    }
    for(i=0;i<6;++i)
    printf("%c",a[i]);
    printf(" ");
}
```

a is an int array with 5 decimal values in it.
pp is a function which converts the decimal numbers into 5 bit binary with no return type.
But when the code is being executed it only prints the result of the a[0] i.e. the value of the 1st data in a and then it stops! 
I cant understand why :3 Pls hlp me out!

My code o/p is : 00100 
But it should be : 00100 00101 00111 00001 01001

Comment: Prints as expected for me (VS 2013).

Comment: Also works for me on Linux / gcc 4.1.2.  How exactly are you compiling this?

Comment: http://ideone.com/sOqC2n works fine here as well!

Comment: It prints all five of them for me. Are you certain that you're running the exact code shown in your question?

Comment: @dbush I've compiled here 
[link] (https://code.hackerearth.com/f9e0fan?key=54f64be361f5ff5ad360d7322fcae16e)

Comment: MinGW-w64 / GCC 4.9.2, compiles without warning and outputs as expected.

Comment: try `printf(" ");fflush(stdout);`

Comment: @Moinak Debnath Change this for loop     for(i=0;i<6;++i)  printf("%c",a[i]); to printf( "%s", a );

Comment: I wonder whether the run time environment is not able to deal correctly with `printf("%c", a[i]);` when `a[i]` is the terminating null character. I would try `for(i=0;i<5;++i)
    printf("%c",a[i]);`

Comment: One possibility is that you should terminate the output with a newline.  However, on Unix-like systems, exiting the program flushes the output even if it doesn't end with a newline.  But if you want timely output, output a newline after the information that you want to appear.

Comment: @RSahu that seems to be the problem: https://code.hackerearth.com/d04282B

Answer (score 1):

Looks like something wrong with the compiler on hackerearth.com.

I'd recommend getting a real compiler.  If you're on Windows, that would be Visual Studio.  There's a free version available for download.  Alternately, you could install VMWare and install a Linux virtual machine and use gcc.

Comment: Visual Studio passes as a “real compiler?!” /s

Answer (score 1):

It seems that the problem is related to outputing the zero character in the loop

```
for(i=0;i<6;++i)
printf("%c",a[i]);
```

There is no need to output each character separatly. You may change these statements

```
for(i=0;i<6;++i)
printf("%c",a[i]);
printf(" ");
```

to this one

```
printf( "%s ", a );
```

Answer (score 1):

I said in a comment

> I wonder whether the run time environment is not able to deal correctly with `printf("%c", a[i]);` when `a[i]` is the terminating null character. I would try `for(i=0;i<5;++i) printf("%c",a[i]);`

@rpattiso verified that at https://code.hackerearth.com/d04282B.

To fix your problem, use:

```
for(i=0;i<5;++i)
   printf("%c",a[i]);
```

or simply

```
printf("%s", a);
```

Comment: @MoinakDebnath, the run time environment at ideone.com is able to deal with `printf("%c", a[i]);` when `a[i]` is the terminating null character in a graceful manner.